# OpenSCAP for SLES 15 docker container and/or image

Tags: openscap

I see from [this page](https://www.open-scap.org/resources/documentation/security-compliance-of-rhel7-docker-containers/) that it is possible to scan either a running RHEL 7 docker container or the docker image.

Is this only possible for RHEL 7 or can it be done for other operating systems? Specifically interested in SLES.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Right, so I'd love to try it but I don't understand where I get the policy file for SLES from.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, go ahead and tell us how it went for you. The RHEL7 way of scanning containers is to use the [atomic scan](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/05/02/introducing-atomic-scan-container-vulnerability-detection/) functionality, but `oscap-docker` or `oscap-podman` should also work there as well as on other Linux distributions that ship OpenSCAP.

Comment: Would you happen to know where I might get the policy file for SLES?

Comment: Isn't SLES a vendor-supported system? I would ask there.